# Flash CS6 dynamic text display not clear?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, flash-cs6

I am using dynamic text field to store score in it, I have embedded font that I am using and its only one.

But on run time while text changing one character at the left most becomes bogus/strange character, unable to figure out why its happening.

Finally I am using bitmap anti-alias for the dynamic field, it fixes the issue but text is not smooth.

If anyone had the same issue ?

Comment: Perhaps you've ran out of textfield width? Check if you give it more width and get that text, will the symbol be illegible or not.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: I started work on the issue today for screenshot share. I changed back the anti-alias "bitmap anti-alias" to "anti-alias for animation" compiled it and there is no issue, its automatically resolved or either restart of cs6 resolved the issue as I didn't close it yesterday in whole day. Application just get mad after long run :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alternate fonts when prompted. Embed the fonts you chose, save and close your application and restart.

It solved my problem, its more likely that cs6 has this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You may have embedded the font, but have selected the correct character types to be embedded? i.e. if it's a score, then numerals needs to be selected like so:

[image: flash font embedding]

*(The dialog above may look slightly different in CS6, or may be somewhere else, I'm not sure; I don't use CS6)*

Characters that are in the field when compiled will be embedded, and characters that aren't embedded won't render correctly.

Alternatively (instead of embedding), you can select "use device fonts" from the dropdown in the properties panel (if you have created the textfield from within Flash Pro rather than programatically), and that will fix it - literally just experienced this problem with an app I just completed and that was my fix.

If the above doesn't work, then I'm sure that it's something to do with the size of the textfield as mentioned above.

Comment: I already followed the same and more instructions from a post. Textfield size is also fine. Its more likely a cs6 bug.

Answer (score -1):

Changing CLASSIC TEXT to TLF TEXT solved the problem.